# React Firebase Snapshot retrieve all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been scratching my head for a while now over a function that I can't seem to make work in React. I'm creating this basic file manager with the Firebase storage and the Cloud Firestore.

What I'm trying to do is to fetch all children in "files", but in this very process also run a function within the fetching process grabbing the file uploaders name and then push it to my array so I can display the file list with correct information instead of showing an id of the file owner. This is the code that I have so far:

```
export const retrieveLibrary = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchCompanyId().then((companyId) => {
            var allFiles = [];
            database.collection("files").orderBy("uploadDate").get().then((snapshot) => {
                if(!snapshot.empty){
                    snapshot.forEach((singleSnapshot) => {
                    fetchFileOwner(singleSnapshot.data().owner).then((name) => {
                            allFiles.push({key: singleSnapshot.id, downloadLink: singleSnapshot.data().downloadLink, name: singleSnapshot.data().name, type: singleSnapshot.data().type, uploadDate: singleSnapshot.data().uploadDate, password: singleSnapshot.data().password ? true:false, owner: name});
                        })
                    })
                    resolve(Promise.all(allFiles));
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                reject(e);
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Here I'm basically doing everything connected with Firebase and trying to create an array that I can retrieve from a promise.

```
export const fetchFileOwner = id => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.collection("users").doc(id).get().then((userInfo) => {
            resolve(userInfo.data().firstName);
        }).catch((e) => {
            reject(e);
        })
    })
}
```

Pretty simple, grabbing the users first name.

```
fetchLibraryFiles().then((library) => {
  setLibraryFiles(library);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
})
```

This is the function I'm calling to retrieve the full library. As you can probably see, I have tried my best to find a way to do this, but I am not able to retrieve the full array. However, when I remove the fetchFileOwner function call inside retrieveLibrary - it works. What am I doing wrong here and why is it wrong? What is the best way of doing something like this where I have to call other functions and wait for the data retrieved?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Data format is here:
the owner is just a UID tied to an account.
[image: Format]

Comment: I am not sure but try changing snapshot.forEach to snapshot.data().forEach and remove data() from singleSnapShot

Comment: Without seeing the specific data you're working with, the expected results of your queries, and behavior of your code that isn't working the way you expect, it's kind of hard to track what the problem is.

Comment: @dlya I'm afraid that won't change much I'm afraid, it's iterating through valid firebase children, and the whole code is working without the fetchFileOwner function. That's what's killing the code I believe, but I don't have a workaround. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand. However, while the format of the data is valid - the problem occurs when I'm trying to call fetchFileOwner inside the promise, even though that function also retrieves the correct name, it just isn't tied together and it's not working. I have to admit that I'm not the best with promises, and I suppose I have to learn more about it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have now attached image.

Comment: I will say that your use of `new Promise` throughout the code here is completely unnecessary.  Firebase APIs already return promises.  There is no need to wrap them in new promises.

Comment: @DougStevenson How come? My "networking logic" is all stored in separate .js files, and using promises is as far as I'm concerned, one of the only ways to retrieve a "final set of data" in one response from firebase without writing from the API directly in a component.

Comment: You can change the result of a promise by chaining a `then` and returning the new or modified value from that callback.  This is the standard convention for promise handling.  Promise chaining is the convention throughout JavaScript, and results in a fewer lines of code that are easier to read.  async/await syntax is even better.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for this information. Is it too much to ask for, if you could provide a code sample?